# How to set up GitLab CI to run multiple build steps efficiently while indicating at which step it is?

Tags: gradle, gitlab-ci

I am pretty new to GitLab. I've set up pipelines and stages via .gitlab-ci.yml and they seem to work but I've just discovered that some of my assumptions were wrong.

I have a large, multi-project Gradle setup, producing many artifacts. We are in the process of setting up GitLab and I really wanted to make use of the GitLab UI to show the progress of the build. The idea was to nicely indicate to developers and reviewers how far the build got before it failed, something like:

1. Got its dependencies
2. Compiled main code, YAY!
3. Compiled test code, yippie!
4. Passed unit tests, we rock!
5. Passed integration tests, awesome!
6. Passed various static code analysis tests. We're almost good to go!
7. Generated documentation - can we ship it?

I've set up each of these as individual jobs of their individual stages, (incorrectly) assuming that Gradle will be able to do its incremental build magic and that this will be almost as quick as running it as a single step.

Then I noticed that each stage causes what seems to be a Docker container reinitialization. This also means that the Gradle daemon has to restart and has no knowledge of the past. It has to get all the dependencies. I think I could cache these, but it seems that they would be separately cached for each job. Finally, these some jobs end up repeating what jobs before them already did because their output isn't available to them. My thinking that serialized jobs would execute inside the same container instance was proven wrong. Each of the subsequent jobs generally have to repeat what jobs before them already did, significantly increasing the build time.

I think I understand that I could declare artifacts of each job and make them available to dependent jobs that way, but that does not eliminate all of the overhead and adds some of its own - copying the artifacts out to "somewhere" and then back, while also hitting the limits of how much I can pass on. In fact, my unit test job is now failing and I can't see why because of the log size limit, but it seems it has to do only with artifacts (the report) as the unit test pass nicely when I run them outside GitLab.

I also think I understand that the idea behind jobs was to be able to run them in parallel on separate runners. That is a very fine feature and I probably can use them for later stages, but not for (1)-(5) as they heavily rely on a lot of output of at least some of the previous jobs.

I could merge (1)-(5) into a single job (and a single stage) for performance reasons, but then there is no indication in the UI (that I know of) as to how far the build got ... and the logs would be even longer and nastier to figure out even if the log limit got lifted.

Do any of you have any suggestions as to what am I missing / should do here?

Comment: GitLab feature request of shared workspaces may solve the problem https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/29265 when implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further research, I found that this is not possible (yet). Jobs are meant to be units of (potentially) concurrent execution and can only communicate by copying artifacts, obviously.

What I would be interested in is steps lesser than jobs that would be indicated in the UI and that could post their artifacts when they (steps) complete but before the entire job is done. This would eliminate 1-2 minutes of job startup overhead that I am facing now.